# OSGi: Refactor Service into Declarative Service

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-felix, eclipse-virgo

i am getting in touch with OSGi and right now i am a little confused. I am using a hybrid service model meaning a mixture of declarative services and low level api.

Consider the following part declaration placed under OSGi-INF/component.xml:

```
<property name="canHandle" type="String" value="Some kind of stuff"/>
<service>
  <provide interface="foo"/>
</service>
```

and another one

```
<property name="canHandle" type="String" value="Some other Stuff"/>
<service>
  <provide interface="foo"/>
</service>
```

In another bundle i have something like this:

```
bar.createSomething(String type){

ServiceReference[] services FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext()
                .getAllServiceReferences("foo");
for (ServiceReference s : services) {
    if (type.equals(s.getProperty("canHandle")){
        Foo foo = (Foo)FrameworkUtilgetBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext().getService(s);
foo.execute();
```

To make a long story short, i a have a service interface with multiple implementations and at runtime i am using the one which matches a string against the properties. So how can i am dealing with this situation ONLY using declarative services?

We are using Virgo so if it is possible with spring, this would be an option too.

Comment: I always wonder why people choose DS over OSGi Blueprint. What was the reason in your case? I found Blueprint much easier to use (yet I haven't spent much time with DS after much exposure to Spring Framework and hence chose Blueprint).

Comment: The reason is, i am new to the whole OSGi stuff, and have not heard of  Blueprint so far. Guess i will give it a try

Comment: I'm in no way expert to say OSGi Blueprint is better/worse than DS, but if you've got a few minutes of spare time, give the article [Developing OSGi Applications with Blueprint bundles and WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile](http://jaceklaskowski.pl/wiki/Developing_OSGi_Applications_with_Blueprint_bundles_and_WebSphere_Application_Server_V8.5_Liberty_Profile) a try and report. It should guide you through with ease.

Comment: DS is simpler and real OSGi. Blueprint has a model foreign to OSGi and does many more things than just service handling. Worst part of Blueprint is the damping of the dynamics and the giving up in the case of missing dependencies. And of course XML is no joy ... (DS has annotations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a target filter on the `<reference>` element. Or, using the bnd annotations:

```
@Reference(target = "(canHandle=blah)")
public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    // ...
}
```

Now even if there are multiple `Foo` service instances available, only the ones matching the filter `(canHandle=blah)` will be injected into your component.

**Update**

It was clarified that the value to be matched is not known statically. In that case the static filter cannot be used. But you can still use declarative services and check the value of the service property manually, for example:

```
@Reference(multiple = true, dynamic = true)
public void setFoo(Foo foo, Map<String,Object> serviceProps) {
    if ("value".equals(serviceProps.get("canHandle"))) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that you might now get multiple matching instances.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems i am missing something... First of all i haven't heard  of the bnd annotations, i will give it a try. And secondly i don't know the type so how to use the target filter? Depending on the type, i want to consume the service.

Comment: You don't have to use annotations at all. As Neil said, you can set the target attribute on the 'reference' element in your component.xml file, which will then only bind to services matching the filter.

Comment: Ok, but still i don't understand how to apply the filter dynamically.As of now, in the upper example my filter is the "string type" parameter. If i specify the target attribute in the component.xml, isn't it some kind of static? Maybe someone can provide me an example or something? But thanks anyways

Comment: You cannot change the filter dynamically in DS. If you need to do that, you need to use the API. Also, don't use getAllServiceReferences. The All includes services which are not class space compatible with Foo your bundle is using. Just use getServiceReferences. And you can supply the filter string in the getServiceReferences call rather than post processing the results.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise that the filter value changed dynamically. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The filter value can also be set through configuration admin ... this is one of the most powerful aspects of DS that you can define the linkage between service in Config Admin.